# C-Error while compiling using Sublime Text 3

Tags: c, gcc, sublimetext3

I was trying to compile a C program through Sublime Text 3,
but I am getting the following error

> [Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
>       [cmd: ['gcc  -o  && ./']]
>       [dir: C:\Users\ARNAV\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User]
>       [path: C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\adb;D:\Git\cmd;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3]]

Comment: Post the source code your compiling.  Post some information about the compile environment.  Post the compile and link statements

Answer (score 0):

this line:

```
gcc -o && ./
```

says to compile and link then run the resulting.

but does not say what file(s) to compile

but does not say what the executable name is to be

Comment: sir, fixed that error using following code : 
https://hastebin.com/evuxunalin.json